# How to show $[-3, 1)$ with an Absolute value inequality?

Tags: functions, inequality, absolute-value, functional-inequalities

I know I can write the closed form of this interval using this formula:

$|x - \text{center}| ≤ \text{radius}$

if it was $[-3, 1]$ then number $-1$ would be the center and the radius is the distance from center to right and left side of the interval, which here is $2$.

then I can write it as:
$|x + 1| ≤ 2$

but the problem is that it's closed on both sides. $\Rightarrow [-3, 1]$

if I write it as:
$|x + 1| < 2$

then both sides will be open. $\Rightarrow (-3, 1)$

how can I show Its half-open form using an Absolute value inequality? or if it's not possible is there a way to do that using other methods?

my idea was to right $|x + 1| ≤ 2$ and add $x ≠ 1$ after it like this:
$|x + 1| ≤ 2 x ≠ 1$

is this considered an Absolute value inequality?

Comment: A set of the form $|x-c| < r$ will be open and similarly a set of the form $|x-c| \le r$ will be closed. Since the set in question is neither it cannot be expressed in this manner.

Comment: @copper.hat is writing it like this the right way? |x + 1| ≤ 2 x ≠ 1 if not what are the other ways I can show it with an Absolute value inequality?

Comment: There is no right way. It is not clear what your goal is.

Comment: @copper.hat I just want to write an inequality using an absolute value that its answer is [-3, 1). if you wanted to show this interval what would be your approach? excuse me if I've confused you. I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: I would just write it as $[-3,1)$. The English was fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The next disagreement with my teacher has begun. I was asking because he was so strict on finding an answer which it seems there are none.

Comment: Good luck :-). ${}$